# SQL query amendment

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem with the below SQL query.

It returns two rows if data are taken also from union function and product_id is returned from the second part of the query (after union).

Expected result:

- only one row
- product_id only the one hardcoded, not the product_id taken from the table CA_TYPE (even if the settlement_date is taken from the union part)

Current SQL query returns this:
MAX(SETTLEMENT_DATE)    PRODUCT_ID  BOOK_ID
**22.12.2019 00:00  324770793   212344790

23.01.2019 00:00    325199615
212344790**

Expected result:
MAX(SETTLEMENT_DATE)    PRODUCT_ID  BOOK_ID
**23.01.2019 00:00  324770793   212344790**

```
 select max(SETTLEMENT_DATE)
    , product_id
    , book_id 
    from trade t 
    where 1=1
    and product_id = 324770793 
    and book_id = 212344790 
    group by book_id, product_id 
    union 
    select max(SETTLEMENT_DATE) 
    , product_id 
    , book_id 
    from trade t 
    where 1=1 
    and product_id in (
    select product_id from PRODUCT_CA where UNDERLYING_ID IN (324770793)
    and CA_TYPE in ('REDEMPTION', 'AMORTIZATION', 'PAYDOWN', 'EXERCISE', 'EXPIRY', 'MERGER')) 
    and book_id = 212344790 
    group by product_id, book_id;
```

Chat GPT can't help with this - that's really challenging issue.

Comment: You say "product_id only the one hardcoded", but the one hardcoded is a book_id ("book_id = 212344790")

Comment: Yes, the book_id is correctly returned in this query as it's always the same. 

The problem is with the product_id - it should be all the time the one hardcoded in the query, not the one taken from the database, table CA_TYPE.

Comment: Ok, you edited the question as i was commenting. This part, "SELECT product_id FROM PRODUCT_CA WHERE UNDERLYING_ID IN (324770793)", why do you use underlying_id instead of product_id = 324770793? It seems that there are two different product_id for that underlying_id...

Comment: Please don't link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question as editable text (so someone can copy it if they want to try out a solution)

Comment: @mbd, uderlying_id is different column in the table CA_TYPE than product_id - that's the whole problem. Take a look please at the expected results, that I has added - product_id should be all the time the same like the one hard-coded.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: @pablo_dev If I understand it, you have at least a row in table PRODUCT_CA with book_id 212344790 , underlying_id = 324770793 and product_id <> 324770793. If product_id field is meaningless for you in that table (PRODUCT_CA) then maybe you should return underlying_id AS product_id the second part of your query

Comment: @pablo_dev Please remove the rmdbs tag and add a specific system which do you want to use.

Comment: @mbd, book_id is the column in table trade only. 

Yes, you're right - it should return uderlying_id when data are taken from the product_ca (second part of the query, after union).